ORA 01843 not a valid month
What is wrong with the Oracle SQL below? I am getting

[Error] Execution (29: 82): ORA-01843: not a valid month.

SELECT * 
FROM schemaAB.VWHIST 
WHERE Ser='SAT' 
AND START_TIME= ('10/10/2024 5:31:03')


Check out the documentation that covers timestamp literals. WHERE Set='SAT' AND START_TIME= TIMESTAMP '2024-10-10 05:31:03' should work.

Is START_TIME a DATE or a TIMESTAMP?

10/10/2024 5:31:03' is a string, not a date or time. Either use a literal, or explicitly convert your string to a date or timestamp, supplying the appropriate format. Don't rely on implicit conversion or session NLS settings.

By comparing a string literal to a date column, you're relying on the database's data format to perform the conversion. As you can see, this format doesn't match the literal's format, and it fails. It's almost always better to not assume anything about that, and expiclity convert such a string to a date yourself:
SELECT * 
FROM   schemaAB.VWHIST 
WHERE  ser = 'SAT' AND
       start_time = TO_DATE('10/10/2024 5:31:03', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       -- HERE -----^


Thank you all. I agree with Mureinik. I modified my SQL. its working.
